# Synonym for my prefix is master

Tags: riddle, word

- Synonym for my prefix is master.
- Synonym for my suffix is folder.
- Synonym for my infix is about.
- Synonym for my whole is shape.

Comment: Do you mean synonym for my whole in the last clue?

Comment: @Deepthinker101 yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PROFILE

> PRO or PROF is a master

> FILE is a folder

> OF Is about

> PROFILE is a shape

Comment: Very good. ----

Comment: All courtesy of wordhippo hehe